# 401 Unauthorized in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a app in Ionic framework.The api calls data from secured server.When i check the api in browser i am getting this popup.[image]

So i could not use this api in mobile app.i found some solution for this issue nothing worked Here is the code i have tried

```
  var string = username + ":" + password;

    // Encode the String
    var encodedString = btoa(string);

    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'https://creatorup.com/wp-json/users/me', 
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedString }
    })
```

When i use this code i got the response "401 (unauthorized)" error.

Comment: please don't call your variable 'string'...

Comment: your code looks ok... The only thing I see, is that the url in the code and the one in the image (creatorup.com) are not the same. That might explain why the credentials work in the browser, but not in your code